# How to write rules in .htaccess so that it can read two file paths in apache /html folder?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, server

I have a problem but can't find the answer. I've googled for regex and still can not understand. I have two directories in my /var/www/html folder. (1. wp 2. pma). What i want to do is I want to edit .htaccess file in my 
/var/www/html so that it can find for /wp path by default. Means that if the user type "localhost", then the wordpress website will show up. If user type "localhost/pma/" then the phpMyAdmin page will show up. I tried to use the mod_rewrite rule and still cant find the correct regex expression.
It seems so hard for me. I appreciate any help.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
This only makes the wp website show up but it does not make phMyAdmin website show up

Currently, if I type "localhost", then the 'index of' page will come out, but if i type "localhost/pma/", the phpMyAdmin come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following. It will only redirect to wp folder if the URI doesn't start with pma/ so that should work. We also don't redirect if is already wp/ in the URI.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!pma/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!wp/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [NC,L]
```